# The most understandable tutorial for joomla

Tags: joomla

I want to know the most understandable tutorial for joomla.

Comment: +1 - Some of the worst documentation I've seen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at these:

http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template

http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the Joomla [Getting Started](http://www.joomla.org/about-joomla/getting-started.html) guide?
Also the [forums](http://forum.joomla.org/) on the site are pretty active and well-organised.

Answer (score 1):

I like the [Joomla! 1.7 - Beginner's Guide by Hagen Graf](http://cocoate.com/j17). You can choose your preferred language.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one I followed. Lynda has a good tutorial [Here](http://www.lynda.com/Joomla-tutorials/Joomla-Essential-Training/95699-2.html?srchtrk=index:2%0Alinktypeid:2%0Aq%3ajoomla%0Apage:1%0As%3arelevance%0Asa%3atrue%0Aproducttypeid:2). Or there are good video tutorials on Youtube also.

Some good Books for beginners:

- Apress Beginning Joomla! From Novice to Professional by Dan Rahmel
- Joomla for dummies Steven Holzner and Nancy Conner
- Joomla! Start to Finish by Jen Kramer

Answer (score 0):

This is most simle and experimental tutorial for joomla http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla/ . This is also an advanced from joomla http://docs.joomla.org/Developers . specialised in developing component